# Click event not firing on child elements of label in iOS and Android using jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

A button is clicked/tapped to dynamically add a new checkbox label group to the page. The clickable elements added with the checkbox elements inside the  `<label>` element are not tappable on mobile, but they are clickable when viewed on desktop.

**Example on Codepen:**
http://codepen.io/clehnert-psl/pen/ByqxmY/

(click "1x" at the bottom of the screen for better display on mobile)

**Intended behaviour (can be seen working properly on a desktop browser):**

After tapping/clicking the "Add attribute" `<a>` ui-button, a new checkbox item will appear under the last one where custom text can be entered by the user. On desktop browsers, the "Save" `<button>` successfully "saves" the entered text in the new ui-checkbox item. After the item is saved, the text can again be clicked to edit or add to the entry.

**The problem:**

On mobile (iOS and Android), the two elements inside the `<label>` element with click listeners do not fire — the "save" `<button>` and the text `<input>` (which can be clicked after it is saved to again edit the text).

The "Delete" `<a>` (the X), works on both mobile and desktop to delete any added checkbox items. This is appended after the `<label>` element. Both the "Save" and `input type="text"` clickable elements work properly if added to the page outside the label, but these items—especially the `<input type='text'>`—need to be children of the `<label>` element for proper layout.

**How can I make the children of the `label` element clickable/tappable on mobile?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's now working](http://codepen.io/clehnert-psl/pen/vOBgGq/)

It was as simple as binding to the `touchstart` event in addition to the click event for the elements in question.

Instead of:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox > label > input:text', function (e){...}
```

It's this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.ui-checkbox > label > input:text', function (e){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to [CCL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533191/cll).

To avoid having the function being fired twice in a row when using both `click` and `touchstart` try something like:

```
var preventDoubleFire = Date.now();
$( document ).on( 'click touchstart', '.selector', function( e ) {
    var millis = Date.now();
    if ( millis - preventDoubleFire < 200 ) return;
    preventDoubleFire = millis;
    // your code here
} );
```